# Why are Futures in scala realised using a collection in the companion object?

Tags: scala

I'm not sure whether I chose the right title for my question..

I'm interested as to why the collection in the companion object is defined. Am I mistaken that this collection will have only one `f` in it? What I am seeing is a collection with exactly one element.

Here's the Future I'm dealing with:

```scala
trait Future[+T] { self =>
  def onComplete(callback: Try[T] => Unit): Unit

  def map[U](f: T => U) = new Future[U] {
    def onComplete(callback: Try[U] => Unit) =
      self onComplete (t => callback(t.map(f)))
  }

  def flatMap[U](f: T => Future[U]) = new Future[U] {
    def onComplete(callback: Try[U] => Unit) =
      self onComplete { _.map(f) match {
        case Success(fu) => fu.onComplete(callback)
        case Failure(e)  => callback(Failure(e))
    } }
  }

  def filter(p: T => Boolean) =
    map { t => if (!p(t)) throw new NoSuchElementException; t }
}
```

Its companion object:

```scala
object Future {
  def apply[T](f: => T) = {
    val handlers = collection.mutable.Buffer.empty[Try[T] => Unit]
    var result: Option[Try[T]] = None

    val runnable = new Runnable {
      def run = {
        val r = Try(f)
        handlers.synchronized {
          result = Some(r)
          handlers.foreach(_(r))
        }
      }
    }

    (new Thread(runnable)).start()

    new Future[T] {
      def onComplete(f: Try[T] => Unit) = handlers.synchronized {
        result match {
          case None => handlers += f
          case Some(r) => f(r)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In my head I was imagining something like the following instead of the above companion object (notice how I replaced the above `val handlers ..` with `var handler ..`):

```scala
object Future {
  def apply[T](f: => T) = {
    var handler: Option[Try[T] => Unit] = None
    var result: Option[Try[T]] = None

    val runnable = new Runnable {
      val execute_when_ready: Try[T] => Unit = r => handler match {
        case None => execute_when_ready(r)
        case Some(f) => f(r)
      }
      def run = {
        val r = Try(f)
        handler.synchronized {
          result = Some(r)
          execute_when_ready(r)
        }
      }
    }

    (new Thread(runnable)).start()

    new Future[T] {
      def onComplete(f: Try[T] => Unit) = handler.synchronized {
        result match {
          case None => handler = Some(f)
          case Some(r) => f(r)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So why does the function `execute_when_ready` leads to stackoverflow, but that's not the case with `handlers.foreach`? what is the collection is offering me which I can't do without it? And is it possible to replace the collection with something else in the companion object?

Comment: You can register as many `onComplete` calls as you want; that is why it is a collection.

Comment: As to why your implementation leads to stack overlow, it's because it just keeps calling itself, when `handler` is`None`.  Also, you are synchronizing on `handler`, and then reassigning it, which will lead to a race condition. And,  of course, you are throwing away the previous handler as mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The collection is not in the companion object, it is in the `apply` method, so there is a new instance for each `Future`. It is there because there can be multiple pending `onComplete` handlers on the same `Future`.

Your implementation only allows a single handler and silently removes any existing handler in `onComplete` which is a bad idea because the caller has no idea if a previous function has added an `onComplete` handler or not.

As noted in the comments, the stack overflow is because `execute_when_ready` calls itself if `handler` is `None` with no mechanism to stop the recursion.